# Find item by filter or get any

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have collection of objects where I need find specific one and if not found  return any or first.

For instance:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo {
    Long id;

    FooType type;
}
```

and I want do something like that:

```
Foo foo = setOfFoos.stream()
      .filter(f -> f.getType() == TYPE_A)
      // not found my type, return any
      .orElseFirst();
```

Can you provide me some nice fancy solution from java 8? Thank you.

Comment: *if not found return any or first.* - doesn't make much sense IMHO, any could include first as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in this way, If you have any matching ones return the first matching one else pick random one

```
foo.stream()
   .filter(f -> f.getType() == TYPE_A)
   .findFirst()
   .orElse(foo.get(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(foo.size())));
```

Or you can also get the first element if non of them satisfied filter

```
foo.stream()
   .filter(f -> f.getType() == TYPE_A)
   .findFirst()
   .orElse(foo.get(0));
```

Comment: You take “any” seriously… just `get(0)` would be sufficient too.